# Switching to next level doesn't work in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I've had very strange problem with my pygame code, that I can't decipher. I've checked the internet, but found nothing usefull. Every time I try to play my game, switching from 2nd to 3rd level won't work. The game just crashes and gives me next error:

```
 File "C:\Users\Moji podatki\Documents\Python programi\Podmornica\submarine.py", line 883, in naris
screen.blit(mine, (self.x1, self.y1))
pygame.error: display Surface quit
```

But as I checked this part of code I couldn't understand why this error in the first place, because I checked, if I wrote the part, that switches and I did:

```
if self.life1 < 0 and self.life2 < 0:
    screen.blit(end, (312, 384))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(1000)
    level3()
```

The error message however points at this part and I have no idea why:

```
def draw(self):
        if not self.explosion1:
            self.frame1 = (self.x1, self.y1, 84, 196) 
            #pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,125,125), self.frame, 2)
            screen.blit(mine, (self.x1, self.y1))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), self.expl_frame1, 2) 
            screen.blit(expl, (self.x1, self.y1))
            explosion.play()
        if not self.explosion2:
            self.frame = (self.x2, self.y2, 84, 196) 
            #pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,125,125), self.frame, 2)
            screen.blit(mine, (self.x2, self.y2))
        else:
            #pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), self.expl_frame2, 2) 
            screen.blit(expl, (self.x2, self.y2))
            explosion.play()
```

Can someone please explain where is problem?

Comment: Did you call `pygame.quit()` anywhere?

Comment: Not in this function

Comment: No. Only at the very begining of the code in menu.

Comment: It did  not work

Answer (score 0):

If it crashed by not responding, it might be because of `time.sleep(1000)`, and if I were you I would add `pygame.display.flip()` at the end of the main game loop, if you'd like the ending screen to stay there add

```py
frame = 0
# main loop here

# erase all here
# rendering stuff here (make sure they're all here so they get rendered at the back layer)

if dead '''idk, perhaps make a dead var''' and not frame > 100 '''increase the num for it to stay there for a longer period of time''' :
    screen.blit(end, (312, 384))
    frame += 1

display.flip()
```

I really hope this helps.

Comment: It keeps crashing. By crashing I mean game turns off completely and I see just this error I described.

Comment: Oh OK, I'll make an edit once I find the solution. EDIT: Could I see the `level13()` function please?

Comment: I think the "premik" sprite has a `pygame.quit()` statement near the end of it's definition, could that be doing it?

Comment: Oh, thanks now it works. I wonder how I didnćt saw that mistake earlier.

Comment: lel, happy to help. :)